# How to catch any words in TfidfVectorizer by token_pattern

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I'd like to catch any words separated by just space in TfidfVectorizer, even if the words like "0" "a" "x" "0?0" and so on.
I wrote the below code for this purpose.

However, maybe, this code doesn't work well.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf = False, token_pattern=r"[^ ]+")
```

P.S.

I could get a right pattern matching by using '\b' .
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for word boundaries:

```
\b\S+\b
```

Explanation:

- `\b` looks for a word boundary, in the first instance of usage it will look for the start of a word (first words after a newline or anything after a space (or type of whitespace))
- `\S+` matches non whitespace characters at least once (the word you are looking for)
- Second `\b` matches end of word matched

Usage:

For string: `Greetings from Spain` it'd match `Greetings` , `from` and `Spain`

Comment: thank you so much your answer. I have never known '\b' meta character.  I will try it soon!

Comment: I am using token_pattern='[^ ()]+' but unable to capture url , I want to capture url also and token_pattern has a constraint of capturing only 1 group